# Payment method required for license tester on google play

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is it necessary to add a payment method for license tester on google play?

I have added my email id as a license tester in google play developer console. but still when I make some purchase it ask me to add payment method and not showing any test purchase dialog.

I have to test subscriptions so can't use static response.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We have multiple test phones with different test logins, but don't want to add payment info to them

Answer (score 5):

It takes some time after adding a license tester to see the test payment options (From my experience usually about a day or so).
Then you should see 2 test cards "Test card, always approves" and "Test card, always declines".

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that, it only enables the checkbox from owners account.